# git push xcrun: error: active developer path does not exist

Tags: git-push, xcrun

i recently deleted xcode 6 beta 3 and installed xcode 6 beta 6

when i entered gitpush in the terminal this happened

xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)

Comment: The message would suggest you should do something like `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app`. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you just upgraded to mojave and got this, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path

Answer (score 37):

Try pasting this in the **terminal**:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app
```

It will update the **path**, for the new Xcode name.

Another alternative is just changing the app name back to Xcode, this, of course, considering you don't have the current one installed.

Answer (score 25):

Also, to remove dependency from XCode app you can manually install Command line developer tools and use the following command to update developer path:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

Comment: This helped me a lot as most other solutions I found were dependent on xcode still being on the system. I wanted to do it without xcode

Comment: Recent update to El Capitan, never had XCode installed, executing this gave me: `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/'`

Comment: Update: running `brew doctor` multiple times helped - had to add _/usr/local/sbin_ back to bash profile, had to rerun `xcode-select --install`. brew pointed out that El Capitan upgrade is known to bork this. :)

All working again.

Comment: This  Solution helped me solve my problem for using git without Xcode in the system.

Answer (score 15):

**Open xcode and navigate to preferences...**

[image]

**Select Location of xcode from command line tools.**

[image]
**After that perform command from terminal.**

Answer (score 8):

Even i also faced the same problem after updating my XCode to 6.3

Resolved my problem by Updating Command line tools

$ sudo xcode-select -switch /

Answer (score 0):

Just try this in the terminal:
sudo xcode-select --reset