# Can't use Go command line on mac os

Tags: macos, go

I want to use command `go get`,but it throws an exception

[image]

But i had installed the command line tools.

[image]

system:macOs sierra 10.12.6

go:1.9.2

**EDIT:**
Error messages:

```
go get github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin 
/Users/famoss/files/goworkspace/src/github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
package github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin: exit status 1
```

Comment: You don't need to use sudo. Also please add error messages as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: @tkausl sorry,i edited the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the recommendations of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35009531/6309):

- either select the XCode version you want to use (directly in XCode Preferences)
- or try the suggested `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app`
- or try a `sudo xcode-select --reset`

See also "[git push xcrun: error: active developer path does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572947/6309)" for an alternative approach.